# Is there any reference / mention about Jeen Mataji in Hindu epics or Vedas?

Tags: gods, devi

My mother believe in [Jeen Mataji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeenmata). I've also visited the temple in childhood. But I feel it's just a belief made by people of Rajasthan state. (Not saying it's a bad thing). But I'm not sure about it.

So I want to know if there any reference / mention about Jeen Mataji in Hindu epics or Vedas? Could she be avatar of someone?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to HSE.!! Please visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se), to get familiar with our site. Further, kindly have a look at: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Have an enriching Journey ahead.